# iOS Xamarin WKWebView Not Showing Popups

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've been trying to show this KYC webpage on WKWebView by calling the below method:

```
    private void KYCLink(string obj)
    {
        WKWebView webView = new WKWebView(new CGRect(0, 0, this.MainWebView.Frame.Width, 
        this.MainWebView.Frame.Height), new WKWebViewConfiguration());
        webView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill;
        webView.NavigationDelegate = new WK_KYCWebViewDelegate();
        webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
       
        NSUrl Link = new NSUrl(new System.Uri(obj).AbsoluteUri);
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(Link));
        this.MainWebView.AddSubview(webView);
    }

    public class WK_KYCWebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
    {
       //empty
    }
```

which doesn't shows popup to access FaceID camera, where as if i open the link in Safari browser it shows the popup (Am not familiar with swift).
Would really appreciate some help.
Thanks All.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you add the relevant privacy in info.plist ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT : i have added NSFaceIDUsageDescription in info.pList for Face ID to unlock our app. Also, included permissions for camera, photo library and fonts to use. In terms of Privacy, nothing added. Any specific keyword that you are looking for so i can share???

Comment: Could you share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT i was actually trying to get this happen but couldn't due to security reasons of the links that are used in our app.....

Comment: If so you could open a public website in your app like google.com to check if the camera function can work in it .